# Find all rows that are not related

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a User MySql table and a Role table. They are related over Relation_RoleUser table (many_to_many).

My problem is, when I want to find all rows (users) that are not related to a specific role. In the following code I tried to find all users without role.id=2:

```
SELECT * FROM `User` `U` 
LEFT JOIN `Relation_RoleUser` ON U.id = Relation_RoleUser.User_id
WHERE Relation_RoleUser.User_id IS NULL OR Relation_RoleUser.Role_id <> 2
GROUP BY `U`.`id`
```

But MySql looks only for one related row in Relation_RoleUser and returns the user if no related row exists or Role_id of this first found row is not 2.

But I want that all related rows are checked in one query, if its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all users who have no role at all? The following will do it:

```
SELECT * FROM `User` `U` 
LEFT JOIN `Relation_RoleUser` ON U.id = Relation_RoleUser.User_id
WHERE Relation_RoleUser.User_id IS NULL
GROUP BY `U`.`id`
```

Edit: Sorry, I get what you're asking now. This should give you the results you're expecting:

```
SELECT * FROM `User` `U` 
LEFT JOIN `Relation_RoleUser` ON U.id = Relation_RoleUser.User_id AND Relation_RoleUser.Role_id = 2
WHERE Relation_RoleUser.User_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY `U`.`id`
```

Comment: Hi, no, I want all users who are not related to one specific role. in example the role with id 2. So, yes, I want to find all users who arent in role 2!

Comment: Edit to answer the question :)